# deviceReady not working in PhoneGap application

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

Here is my code:

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("on device ready");
     //var db = window.openDatabase("Weather", "1.0", "Weather DB", 1000000);
     //db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

it is not working. 
also the on device ready and document.addevent listener is outside the

```
    $(document).ready(function() {});
```

Comment: It works for me! Have you added the library for cordova?

    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        alert('Test');
      }, true);
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parenthesis.

This works for me.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```